# vb.net how would I load a wave front obj?

Tags: vb.net, wavefront

I'm trying to load a `Wavefront OBJ` onto my form in `vb.net`.

Most of the tutorials I saw is basically replacing the entire form with a `directX` form.

But I don't want that id like to just show the model in my current form. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .net GDI isn't really meant for 3D rendering. Technically I suppose it is theoretically possible... but you would have to figure out how to get GDI to accept the Z coordinate, which I don't believe is prebuilt into it. The rendering performance would likely be poor though. Here is a link to the closest thing I could find on the subject:

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?650905-Rotating-3D-Cube-Using-VB-NET-and-GDI

If your model is more complex than that you are going to want to use DirectX, XNA, OpenGL or some other 3D rendering engine. Especially if you are expecting the model to move\animate.

If it is just meant to be a static model why not just prerender it and use a jpeg or bmp file?